# Small problem to run any source code in Java

Tags: java, compilation, execution

When creating any source code, as in the example below, and after clicking the button to execute, the result of the code execution does not appear, and instead always appears the phrase: "Built Successfully".

[image]

Not even clicking on F6 or Shift + F6 works.
Please, how do you go about showing the code result on the screen?

Comment: You probably have a different class with a `main` method configured as the "main entry point".  1. Check the other classes in the project; 2. Check project properties "Build/Run/Main Class"

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have another class with a `main` method which is configured to run as the "main class"

## Option #1

Make sure the source file is selected in the editor and use  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to "Run file"

## Option #2

Right click on the project node and select "Properties"

[image]

Navigate to "Build" > "Run" and verify the "Main Class" property

[image]

Click "Browse" (next to "Main Class") and select the class you want to act as the "Main Class"

[image]